Excitons and Photoluminescence (PL)
I am looking into excitonic resonance in PL intensity and I was reading about how the lower the binding energy the lower the PL intensity.
I understand that the lower the binding energy the less bound and subsequently the states are less stable but how does this result in a lower PL intensity?

I suggest citing the textbook and, if possible, even quoting the relevant passage, to make the context fully clear - otherwise, one can only guess what is meant by this statement.

Lower binding energy for an exciton means that the luminescence frequency is close to that of the band gap. This means that lesser energy is needed for the exciton to be destroyed via interaction with other electrons, thermal fluctuations, various broadening mechanisms, etc.
Thus, given the same intensity of the excitation pulse (presumably creating the same number of excitons), we will have less excitons actually releasing their energy by emitting photons, i.e., via absorption - hence lower intensity.
In other words, what is in play here is statistics, not the inherent properties of exciton (dipole moment/oscillator strength.)
